# Failed to call CGEvent.tapCreate if run from Xcode but succeeded from Terminal

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I want to write an application to capture the media keys event and modify it for further use. After referring to https://github.com/nevyn/SPMediaKeyTap, I started my code with Swift 4., which is as follows:

```
func tapEventCallback(proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, event: CGEvent, refcon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? {
    let keyCode = event.getIntegerValueField(.keyboardEventKeycode)
    print("Key code: \(keyCode)")
    return Unmanaged.passRetained(event)
}

class MediaKeyTaps: NSObject {

    var eventPort: CFMachPort?
    var eventPortSources: CFRunLoopSource?

    @objc func eventTapThread() {
        let tapThreadRL = CFRunLoopGetCurrent()
        CFRunLoopAddSource(tapThreadRL, eventPortSources, .commonModes)
        print(CGEvent.tapIsEnabled(tap: eventPort!))
        CFRunLoopRun()
    }

    func startListening() {
        eventPort = CGEvent.tapCreate(tap: .cgSessionEventTap, place: .headInsertEventTap, options: .defaultTap, eventsOfInterest: CGEventMask(NX_SYSDEFINED), callback: tapEventCallback, userInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(self).toOpaque()))

        if let eventPort = eventPort {
            print("Succeed to create tap…")
            eventPortSources = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorSystemDefault, eventPort, 0)
            Thread.detachNewThreadSelector(#selector(eventTapThread), toTarget: self, with: nil)
        } else {
            fatalError("Failed to create event tap…")
        }
    }
}
```

A really weird thing is, if I run this code from terminal, which by running `swift test.swift`, it could work but can **only get the mouse button event**. All the keyboard key press event are missed. However, if these codes are put into a Cocoa Application project, and run from Xcode, the `CGEvent.tapCreate` will return `nil`. In addition, I have checked the return value of `AXIsProcessTrusted()`, which is `true`.

Comment: The problem that `CGEvent.tapCreate` returned `nil` has been fixed by set the `App Sanbox` entry in entitlements File to `NO`.